# Why StringBuffer has a toStringCache while StringBuilder not?

Tags: java, java-8, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In JDK 8, `StringBuffer` class has a `toStringCache`, while `StringBuilder` doesn't.

```
/**
 * A cache of the last value returned by toString. Cleared
 * whenever the StringBuffer is modified.
 */
private transient char[] toStringCache;
```

But why?

- One possible reason I can think of is that StringBuffer is already synchronized so a cache can be implemented easier.
- Or maybe historically StringBuffer was implemented this way so old code depends heavily on this feature?

Given modern JVM with escape analysis and biased locking, is the difference relevant anymore?

Comment: Your first guess is correct.

Comment: @Flown Is it worth it? Will there be any performance boost? More code means more bugs.

Comment: If you call `StringBuffer::toString` numerous times, then there will be a benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might help to consider the historical context. `StringBuilder` was introduced with Java 5, since it has been recognized, that `StringBuffer` isn’t well suited for its actual use cases.

The newly introduced `StringBuilder` has been designed for the major use case of being constructed, used and immediately dropped afterwards, in a purely local context. Therefore, it doesn’t provide any synchronization and it doesn’t bother optimizing the rare case of its `toString()` method being called multiple times without an in-between change (when does this happen in real life at all?), especially as, indeed, providing the caching feature without sacrificing the performance advantage of no thread synchronization, is somewhere between “hard” to “impossible”.

While `StringBuilder` is documented to be not thread safe, so you know inconsistent things could happen when calling methods on it concurrently, the class `String` is guaranteed to be thread safe through immutability, hence, it must not be allowed that `StringBuilder`’s absence of synchronization can causes inconsistencies in already constructed strings and, not sharing the array between `String` and `StringBuilder` at all, is the safest solution.

So why is this optimization there, if it hardly ever has a benefit in real life? Well, because it’s there since a very long time, most likely even since Java 1.0 and it’s not worth changing anything in the class `StringBuffer`. Its presence may not have any real advantage, but neither has removing it, which would require new testing and so on and could turn out to be the [space bar overheating feature](https://xkcd.com/1172/) for some application…

You may notice that back-then, in Java 1.x, a lot of design decision were made that may look strange today. Overusing `synchronized` in fundamental classes is one of them, this hardly ever helping optimization another one. At that time, even the implications of immutability were not well understood, which is why we have redundant methods like [`String.valueOf(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char:A-) and [`String.copyValueOf(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#copyValueOf-char:A-), plus the opportunity to use [`new String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-)…

Comment: I didn't know String.copyValueOf(char[])

Comment: @ntysdd: …and the existence of these redundant `copyValueOf` methods is something we don’t need to remember. At least for our daily programmer’s work.

Comment: @ntysdd (and @Holger) Certainly `copyValueOf` methods are irrelevant today. Of historical note is that pre JDK 1.0, the `String(char[])` constructor and `valueOf(char[])` methods (both public) simply stored the reference to the argument in a newly constructed string. Naturally this led to mutable strings! The `copyValueOf` methods were added to copy the arrays, then the constructors and `valueOf` were modified to make copies too, leaving the `copyValueOf` methods redundant. However, they were never cleaned up.

Comment: @StuartMarks Horrible.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your first guess is highly accurate, since `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe and an instance can be shared across multiple threads, implementing such a cache would require additional synchronization, this would defeat the purpose of `StringBuilder` in the first place.

As to why this would be needed, it boils down to the `new String(...)` constructor that is used; in case of `StringBuffer` that used the constructor `String(array, boolean)` the comment says:

> Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the speed advantage does not materialize if you call `StringBuffer.toString` a single time, as [the caller](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#669) did a copy then. There could be a small benefit, only in the rare case of multiple invocations without changes. This `String` constructor provides more advantages for factories directly working on a correctly sized `char[]` buffer without reusing it afterwards, say `String.concat(String)`, `String.replace(char,char)`, `Integer.toString(int)`, etc.