# Why does StringBuffer's toString() method use Arrays.copyOfRange(value, 0, count)?

Tags: java

StringBuffer's SourceCode has a variable `toStringCache`, but only  in the `toString()` method does it get a value:

```
public synchronized String toString() {
        if (toStringCache == null) {
            toStringCache = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, 0, count);
        }
        return new String(toStringCache, true);
    }
```

Why not use `toString` like `StringBuilder`:

```
return new String(value, 0, count);
```

Is there any particular reason for this difference?

Comment: what java version are you using ?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to know this, but the difference between the StringBuilder and StringBuffer is that the first one is not thread safe, and was introduced in java 1.5 as a replacement of StringBuffer when used in a single thread. I guess the implementation differences will have to do with this.

Comment: @Aomine  java1.8

Comment: @Juan  I will have  a look at the version records later

Comment: some useful info here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294579/why-stringbuffer-has-a-tostringcache-while-stringbuilder-not

Comment: As an aside, note that both the code for StringBuilder toString and StringBuffer toString have been modified to some extent in JDK9.

Comment: @Aomine   thanks a lot  ,you provided very useful  message to  me

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer was it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten year ago,

Comment: @Juan I am willing to bet any code using StringBuffer in a multithreaded way isn't using it correctly. ;) ie.e. even for multi-threaded you should use StringBuilder and do your own synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in java are immutable, meaning if you just call `new String(char_array)` it will make an internal immutable copy of the array. Any changes to the original `char_array` will not be reflected in the new string. StringBuilder, however, is using a package private constructor String(char[] value, boolean share). It actually allows it to use a shared array. But now it has to make sure this shared array is not modified. So it makes a copy and creates a string with it.

`new String(value)` would've worked just fine too, but then every call to StringBuilder.toString() will create a new copy of the array. So it's a performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The `toStringCache` array is shared with the string created. This avoids copying the array content at each `toString()` call.

Since `StringBuffer` is synchronized it can ensure that the `value` array will not be modified during the call, and thus the shared array will not receive inconsistent data. `StringBuilder`, as an unsynchronized class, can not give this guaranty.

The following example might produce output "aa" if `StringBuilder` had the same `toString()` implementation as `StringBuffer`.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("ab");

// Thread A, parallel with B
System.out.println(s.toString());

// Thread B, parallel with A
s.reverse();
```

Comment: the  value  is  also stored  in its super class  , it is  synchronized

Comment: Correct, but imagine Thread A calls `StringBuilder.toString()`. Before the method returns Thread B modifies the content of the same `StringBuilder`. Then it may be possible that the array copy would copy an inconsistent state when thread A completes the call.